# Does using SQL Datasource conform to DAL

Tags: asp.net, data-access-layer

Does using SQL Datasource within an ASP.Net page conform to DAL or does it upset the convention of using layered programming? Or, perhaps I am mixing concepts for lack of understanding either.

Specifically, does using sql datasource to populate a datagrid break the layered approach to programming? The sqldatasource holds the select query in the presentation layer, is this correct?

Comment: You could argue it either way. Literally, it is a separate class ('layer') that exists to access data, so you could say that it is part of a DAL. OTOH, the point of a DAL is to abstract away the source of the data (database, filesystem, etc). SqlDataSource requires the layer above it to have implementational knowledge of the data source, keeping them tightly coupled, removing the benefit of a DAL. A more important question is whether a DAL is a useful abstraction worth the tradeoffs within the context of webforms and your particular case. You don't want to follow blindly follow patterns.

Comment: +1 you should have made this an answer.

Comment: I flagged it as opinion based and didn't want to play both sides by adding an answer :) If it's still open when I'm done with all my morning meetings I'll add an answer that expands on the comment and weighs some of the tradeoffs.

Comment: @Turch make your comment an answer. I think it should be.